# How to get HTMLElement.click() to work within Chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I would like to use html.element.click() within my extension to click on tabs and get DOM element values from this webpage:  https://realtime.demo.sonicwall.com/main.html.  I've tried many different scripts including the send message, and this is the latest version I found online, but all wind up producing the following error.  The error I get is, "VM2551:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null".

manifest.json

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "SonicWall Audit",
"version": "1.0",
  "icons": {
  "128": "icon.png"
    },
"background": {
"persistent": false,
"scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
"content_scripts": [{
"matches": ["*://*.realtime.demo.sonicwall.com/*"],
"js": ["content.js"]
    }],
"browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Run Gen6 Audit",
     "default_popup": "index.html"
},
"permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "<all_urls>"
],

"permissions": ["activeTab"]
}
```

test.js

```
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log("Popup DOM fully loaded and parsed");

    function modifyDOM() {      
        //You can play with your DOM here or check URL against your regex
        console.log('Tab script:');
    document.getElementById('j1_64_anchor').click();
        console.log(document.body);
        return document.body.innerHTML;
    }

    //We have permission to access the activeTab, so we can call chrome.tabs.executeScript:
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        code: '(' + modifyDOM + ')();' //argument here is a string but function.toString() returns function's code
    }, (results) => {
        //Here we have just the innerHTML and not DOM structure
        console.log('Popup script:')
        console.log(results[0]);
    });
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <button id="test">TEST!</button>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I edited the code so that it has the location of the click.  Thanks.

Comment: `document.getElementById` will return `null` if 'j1_64_anchor' can not be found. And `null` does not have `click` method on it. `null` just.... null

Comment: That ID exists on the page I included.   That command works fine in the Console.

Comment: Or it's inside an iframe and you were inspecting it in devtools so the [console context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KLb0.jpg) was switched to the iframe.

Comment: Yep, it is inside an iFrame, I guess I left that part out.  Hmm, ok.  Any idea on how to pull it.  I guess it has to do with the context?

Comment: It does have iFrames within it, but this id is part of the NavBar and is not in the iFrame.

Comment: The navbar is in one iframe. You have to invoke `chrome.tabs.executeScript` with `allFrames:true`. And, as mentioned before, check for the existence of the element before calling the `click` method, like `var elem = document.getElementById('j1_64_anchor'); if (elem) elem.click();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got it to work!  Thank you all!  Fortunately the iframes are all in the same domain!

```
    function modifyDOM() {      
            //You can play with your DOM here or check URL against your regex
            console.log('Tab script:');
            console.log(document.body);
            var iframe = document.getElementById('outlookFrame');
            var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
            innerDoc.getElementById('j1_64_anchor').click();
            return document.body.innerHTML;
        }
```